# mysql syntax error check manual

Tags: java, mysql

i am using the following code and it gives me an error that says `you have an error in mysql syntax`. What would be the problem?

```
 public void Saved()
    {

        try {
             String sql="insert into std(ADM_NO,Form,Student,Parent,Contact)values(?,?,?,?,?)";

                 ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                  ps.setString(1, txtadm.getText());
                  ps.setString(2, txtform.getText());
                  ps.setString(3, txtsname.getText());
                   ps.setString(4, txtpname.getText());
                  ps.setString(5, txtmobileno.getText());


                  ps.execute();
```

Comment: ignore enter code here sorry for that

Comment: Whats the error? post full error details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
String sql="insert into std(ADM_NO,Form,Student,Parent,Contact) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, txtadm.getText());
ps.setString(2, txtform.getText());
ps.setString(3, txtsname.getText());
ps.setString(4, txtpname.getText());
ps.setString(5, txtmobileno.getText());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put white-space before `values(?,?,?,?,?)` in `sql` string.

```
String sql="insert into std(ADM_NO,Form,Student,Parent,Contact) 
             values(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

error is in this line `ps.execute();`
you should use                   `ps.executeUpdate();`
to insert,delete or update use                   `ps.executeUpdate();`
when you are retrieving from datatabase using select query then use                   `ps.execute();`
so you full code would be

```
public void Saved()
    {

        try {
             String sql="insert into std(ADM_NO,Form,Student,Parent,Contact) values(?,?,?,?,?)";

                 ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                  ps.setString(1, txtadm.getText());
                  ps.setString(2, txtform.getText());
                  ps.setString(3, txtsname.getText());
                   ps.setString(4, txtpname.getText());
                  ps.setString(5, txtmobileno.getText());


                  ps.executeUpdate();
```

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

Comment: ps.execute() can be use.

Comment: @EJP I dont find any syntax errors now but you if you think then please let me know.I will edit or delete my answer